# WLOG imposing an order relation

Tags: logic

Let us consider $n$ real variables $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ and a proposition $P(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ that we have to prove is true for all real values of the $a_i$'s.

My question is when can we WLOG impose an order relation $a_1\leq a_2\leq\ldots\leq a_n$ and prove the proposition $P$ for this case and conclude that $P$ is true for all real values of the $a_i$'s ?

I see that this works when $P$ is symmetric in terms of the $a_i$'s but are there any other sufficient conditions regarding when we can impose such a WLOG order relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove: "If WLOG can be applied, then $P$ is symmetric".

Suppose that $P$ is not symmetric. Then, there is a $n$-tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $P(a_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,a_{\sigma(n)})$ has a truth value opposite to $P(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. If we arrange the terms of the $n$-tuple in a increasing order we will get the truth value of $P(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ or that of $P(a_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,a_{\sigma(n)})$, but never both, so WLOG can not be applied for every $n$-tuple. Contradiction.

(WLOG means here that if we rearrange the terms of the $n$-tuple in increasing order, we get the same truth value).